# Anonymous users are unable to access DependencyHandler.axd with forms authentication and outpucache

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, outputcache, client-dependency

anonymous users are unable to access DependencyHandler.axd with forms authentication and outpucache.

Enable forms authentication

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10080" requireSSL="true" />
</authentication>
```

Configure output cache

```
  <caching>
    <outputCache enableOutputCache="true" defaultProvider="Memcached">
      <providers>
        <add name="Memcached" type="Enyim.Caching.Web.MemcachedOutputCacheProvider, Enyim.Caching.Web" />
      </providers>
    </outputCache>
  </caching>
```

Configure CDF:

```
    <clientDependency loggerType="" version="15">
    <fileRegistration>
      <providers>
        <clear />
      </providers>
    </fileRegistration>
    <compositeFiles defaultFileProcessingProvider="CompositeFileProcessor" defaultFileMapProvider="XmlFileMap" compositeFileHandlerPath="~/DependencyHandler.axd">
      <fileProcessingProviders>
        <clear />
        <add name="CompositeFileProcessor" type="ClientDependency.Core.CompositeFiles.Providers.CompositeFileProcessingProvider, ClientDependency.Core" urlType="Base64QueryStrings" persistFiles="false" />
      </fileProcessingProviders>
    </compositeFiles>
  </clientDependency>
```

it looks like [FormsAuthenticationModule](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/FormsAuthenticationModule.cs) skips .axd files, so it does not initialize the **User** then when execute [OutputCacheModule](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/OutputCacheModule.cs) it throws exception because the user is null onLeave event.

the exception is in line [1882](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpContext.cs,a5d9c239fcc2d9d8) in `RequestRequiresAuthorization()`

exception details:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Web.HttpContext.RequestRequiresAuthorization()
   at System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule.OnLeave(Object source, EventArgs eventArgs)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

allow DefaultAuthentication solved the problem

I had these configuration in the config file

```
  <remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
  <remove name="AnonymousIdentification" />
```

Removing the above 2 lines fixed the problem